# like history and fc but for a personalized list of useful commands

Tags: bash, environment-variables, alias, command-history

I have spent a few hours trying to get an easy access to my most useful commands I have to use in a certain environment, I have the "incredible" idea of using history for that purpose, to summarize, I have a file named .bash_history_template with those commands I always use and I added something like this:

> ~/.bash_history_template >> ~/.bash_history

in ~/.bashrc to get easy access to an ordered list of commands I use always (It's more complex but you got the idea)

My question is: Is there any other way of, instead of using history or fc, using another command to get the existing commands located on the file .bash_history_template and using a pretty awesome shortcuts to execute and editing them (like !number or fc number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of @cas answer and this answer is what solved my problem:

```
phew() {
    c="echo 'This is not really my super long winded command'"
    read -p "Hit enter to run: $c"
    $c
}
```

taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62667273/can-bash-write-a-command-to-the-terminal-input

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you're asking for, but an alternative.

Scour your `~/.bash_history` file for frequently-run commands.  Analyse multiple instances of the same command, looking for things that can be turned into variables.

You can also examine the man pages for these commands, for options you might use in future - but don't spend too much time or effort on that, focus on features/options/arguments you're already using. You can always update your scripts to add new features when you actually need them.

Write wrapper scripts to run those commands, taking arguments from the command-line for the variables. If necessary, use `getopts` to handle options for your script. The scripts can be in bash, awk, perl, or whatever you feel comfortable working with and is appropriate for task at hand.

If you use `getopts`, try to use option letters that serve as a useful mnemonic. Or option letters that are common to other programs, especially similar or conceptually-related programs. e.g. if your script needs to do any regex matches use`-i` for case-insensitivity, `-v` to invert a match.  If it takes a list of items (e.g. filenames) from stdin or generates one on stdout, use `-z` for NUL-separated input/output - that way, your script can be safely used in a pipeline with other programs (most of the GNU tools, for example) that work with NUL-separated input.

Create a directory called `~/bin/` and add it to your $PATH (edit your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`).  Save your scripts in ~/bin/.

If some of them need to be run by multiple users (e.g. root AND your user) then consider putting those scripts in `/usr/local/bin/` instead.

Script names will be easier to remember than history line numbers (and won't change as you use the shell).  And you can add comments to each script describing what it does, and what arguments it takes.  Or even add a `-h` or `--help` option.

I've been doing this for decades - almost anything I do more than a few times and am likely to do often gets turned into a script - and the hardest part is thinking up a useful, descriptive name for the script :)

BTW, I recommend running `git init` in your ~/bin/ directory so you can use `git` to keep a revision history of all changes to your scripts.

Comment: I like this idea

Comment: It's a good idea, pretty much standard practice since forever.    It serves your immediate needs and is a great way to practice your script-writing skills.  You'll get much better at it the more you do it, and you'll probably end up revisiting your earlier scripts many times to improve them with techniques you've learnt since you first wrote them/last updated them.

Comment: can you share your github? I'd like to see your scripts

Comment: I don't publish my private scripts on github.   `git` doesn't mean github.  github is just one of many services based on git, and you don't even have to use a remote service to use git. It works just fine as a local revision control system. 
 You don't even need to set a remote or use git push if you don't want to.  You can even run your own remote git repo on your own private servers, using software like gerrit, gitlab, gitea, launchpad and many others - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git#Git_server. I currently run my own private gitlab server but switching to gitea is on my TODO list.